# QTabWidget does not show up when put into another widget

Tags: qt, tabs

If I set the parent of a QTabWidget to something else than nullptr, it does not show up. However, if I set it to nullptr (and also call m_root->show(), I get a toplevel window. What is wrong?

```cpp
    class topographic_map_multiview:public QWidget
    {
    public:
        explicit topographic_map_multiview(QWidget* parent):
        QWidget{parent},
        m_root{std::make_unique<QTabWidget>(this)},
        m_map{new topographic_map_view_map_view(nullptr)}
        {
            m_root->setContentsMargins(form_indent, 0, 0, 0);
            m_root->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy{
                QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding,
                QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding
            });
            m_map->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy{
                QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding,
                QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding
            });
            m_root->addTab(m_map, "Map view");
            m_map->setObjectName("map_view");
            m_root->setCurrentIndex(0);
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<QTabWidget> m_root;
        topographic_map_view_map_view* m_map;
    };
```

Here is the complete hierarchy:

```
QWidget:: 
    QFormLayout:: 
    QLineEdit::width 
        QWidgetLineControl:: 
    QLabel:: 
    QLineEdit::height 
        QWidgetLineControl:: 
    QLabel:: 
    QLineEdit::pixel_size 
        QWidgetLineControl:: 
    QLabel:: 
    QWidget:: 
        QVBoxLayout:: 
        QLabel:: 
        QWidget::initial_heightmap 
            QTabWidget:: 
                QStackedWidget::qt_tabwidget_stackedwidget 
                    QStackedLayout:: 
                    QWidget::map_view 
                        QHBoxLayout:: 
                        QWidget:: 
                        QWidget:: 
                QTabBar::qt_tabwidget_tabbar 
                    QToolButton:: 
                    QToolButton::
```

Comment: If `m_root` isn't managed by a layout then you might need to call `m_root->show()`.  If that's not the problem then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M Inserting an intermediate QBoxLayout L with `this`as parent, and adding the QTabWidget to L (QTabWidget also has `this` as parent), solves the issue. Maybbe GTK has an easier but less flexible layout model.